# How to pass value of one url to another url as parameter in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

how can I pass a value key from a GET url response to another GET url as a parameter in Angular component ?

The first url needs to be execute first after that only second url must get execute.
Any example that can be done with or without service ?

Comment: please show what u have tried so far.. bcs question is rather unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.apiService.firstAPI().subscribe(res => {
   if(res.body){
    var id = res.body.data[0].id;
     this.apiService.SecondAPI(id).subscribe(res => {

     }
   }
 }
```

this way your second API will be called only when first API response comes.

as for the api service function

```
SecondAPI(id) {
    return this.httpService.get('api/getmyData?id='+id);
}
```

Comment: suppose in response of first API I got data as  `{ "id": 1}` . Now how can I pass this this id to second API as a parameter ?

Comment: i have updated my answer, i hope i covered most of it.

Comment: Nested subscribes is not a good practice. Its theoretically OK to use it in http calls, but will cause issues when you start writing more complex RxJS scenarios. Also, the code will be more readable if you use rxjs operators.

Answer (score 1):

The RxJS way to do this is to use `switchMap`

```
this.http.get('/url1')
.pipe(
     switchMap((res)=>{
          return this.http.get('/url2' + res.id);
     })
)
.subscribe((res)=>{
     // Do whatever
});
```

Comment: Yes , I was unaware of this. Thanks I will try